# Rare exception in Tomcat JSP Jersey app (org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jersey

I'm getting this exception on my JSP application after adding some Java packages which **does not** give to me compilation errors. Those packages are not being used, but they are added.

This exception does not have any portion of my code, is just jersey or Java libraries code, not mine, so I don't know how to solve it.

In Google or SO there is nothing about this rare error not related with my code in the exception log:

```
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
    SEVERE: Exception starting filter jersey
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26415
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner$1.f(FileSchemeScanner.java:86)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scanDirectory(FileSchemeScanner.java:83)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scanDirectory(FileSchemeScanner.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scanDirectory(FileSchemeScanner.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scan(FileSchemeScanner.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:225)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:141)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:696)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5652)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jersey 1.x, try upgrading to the latest version (1.19).

I was seeing the same stack trace with a web application that was working fine with Java 7, but got that error when I moved to Java 8. This application was using Jersey 1.15.

See more about this change in the [release notes](https://blog.dejavu.sk/2015/02/13/jersey-1-19-is-released/) of Jersey 1.18. In this post there is a link to the pull request with some comments.

This post has a few months, but I answer in case someone else runs into this issue. It took me a couple of hours to figure out what was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. My IDE silently switched to using a JDK 11. To anybody having the same problem: make sure to use JDK 8.